# How to write text into file without waiting for file closure

Tags: java, performance, file, file-io, buffer-overflow

I am trying to write text into file and I noticed that the file is getting written only when it is closed using close(). This is not a problem when the text is insignificantly small. But since I am sure I am going to get huge chunks of text to write, I would not want the text to overflow my main memory. Is there any better way to do this without overflowing the memory?

```
BufferedWriter outputHandle = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

while(true)
{
    try {
        <DO SOME PROCESSING >
                outputHandle.write(text);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `flush` the buffer...You'd need to test it, but I'm pretty sure the `BufferWriter` will write it's buffer to the file/disk if/when it's full

Comment: @MadProgrammer It works. I would not want to test the other scenario when the buffer becomes full. I cannot take the risk of crashing my laptop :)

Comment: I don't think the buffer is actually that large (kilobytes) - `private static int defaultCharBufferSize = 8192` <- 8 kilobytes by default, but you can change this using `public BufferedWriter(Writer out, int sz)`...

Comment: It depends on what the buffer is connected to. If it's a file, it'd be the size of a page on the disk; it is commonly 4k but depends on the exact file system, OS, ... (update: that was for C library; as MadProgrammer said above in Java it's 8k).

Comment: @Frederic Dumont But isn't the case that the buffer should be connected to main memory? I could see the main memory usage growing in my laptop

Comment: The memory might be growing, but that's very unlikely due to the buffer itself. Without details into what happens in the <DO SOME PROCESSING> step, it's hard to say exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default buffer size of a `BufferedWriter` is 8kb (`private static int defaultCharBufferSize = 8192`), but you can change the buffer size using the [`public BufferedWriter(Writer out, int sz)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#BufferedWriter(java.io.Writer,%20int)) constructor

While you can use [`BufferedWriter#flush`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush()), it's use could affect the performance of your application (as it could increase the disk I/O ... although, most OS's cache this as well).

I think you're prematurely optimising your solution and should test to see if it's actually going to be an issue to start with.  You might even find that you want to increase the buffer size

Answer (score 1):

The buffer is not growing; it's purpose is to lower the cost of writing into a file: writing a character is about as expensive as writing a few kilobytes (in some circumstances, at least), so keeping data in the buffer and only writing when it's full optimizes performances.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @MadProgrammer, flush works .

```
outHandle.flush()
```

Comment: where you should put flush on your program? its in your while or before close?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira You should put it within the while. Say you divide the entire processing into 10 parts. So you can flush after every two parts.